# How to prompt for sudo password with ansible

Tags: ansible, sudo

*As suggested in https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/7742*

How can you make ansible prompt for the sudo password automatically without specifying `--ask-sudo-pass`?

Answer (score 11):

you can use [vars_prompt](//docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html) and prompt into [ansible_become_pass](//docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#connection-variables) to solve this! (`ansible_sudo_pass` for older ansible versions)

```
vars_prompt:
  - name: "ansible_become_pass"
    prompt: "Sudo password"
    private: yes
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply Run your Command with following Ways

1.ansible-playbook main.yml --ask-become

```
  OR
```

2. ansible-playbook main.yml -K

It will ask for sudo password of remote host automatically

Answer (score 0):

Building off @g-roggemans solution, I was able to get this working on Debian 10, Ansible 2.9.9:

```
---

- name: Sample Playbook: Patch Debian/Ubuntu based servers
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: group1, group2, group3
  vars_prompt:
    - name: "ansible_become_pass"
      prompt: "Sudo password"
      private: yes
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  tasks:

  - name: Update and upgrade apt packages
    apt:
      upgrade: yes
      update_cache: yes
      cache_valid_time: 86400 #one day in seconds
```

Then I can run my playbook as follows: **ansible-playbook update_debian.yml**. The key was to add:

```
become: yes
become_user: root
```